# Accessing Connected App From Visualforce

Tags: apex, lightning, connected-apps, session, saml

I'm developing an application which integrates with another services API. This API requires a SAML token to provide authentication. I've created a connected app, and from an execute anonymous call if I invoke the idp url I get back a page which contains the SAML token which I can parse and use to authenticate against the API (if you perform a get against that URL and it detects you don't have javascript enabled which an HTTP request from apex doesn't, it instead provides a button to click that contains the SAML token)

The problem is that I cannot make a request to the connected app from within a visualforce page/lightning app context because the sessionId I get from the userinfo.getSessionId() I use to authorize the get request is only valid for the visualforce/lightning custom code domain, not the standard page domain. How can I make a get request to get the SAML token from the connected app from within my visualforce page, or is there a better way to do this? I feel like this approach is already very hacky, but I don't know of a better way to get the SAML token in Apex that I need to authorized against the endpoint and get an access token from them for further API calls against their API.

TL;DR: How do I make a get request against a standard salesforce page from a lightning component context? Using the Session ID provided by userInfo.getSessionId() does not work when run from within a lightning context, but does work in execute anonymous.

Here is the code for my request as it stands. Nothing too fancy, but just in case it helpds.

```
            //get the URL of the connected app that is stored in a custom meta data record
        req.setEndpoint(SETTINGS.Local_IdP_Initiated_Login_Url__c); //Idp Initiated Login URL
        req.setMethod('GET');
        string token = Userinfo.getSessionId();
        system.debug('Session ID: ' + UserInfo.getSessionId().substring(0,20) + ' --------- ' +UserInfo.getSessionId().substring(20,UserInfo.getSessionId().length()));
        String authorizationHeader = 'sid=' + token;
        req.setHeader('Cookie', authorizationHeader);
        //Tried setting authorization bearer, didn't work with any session token retreived
        //req.setHeader('Authorization', ' Bearer ' + token);
        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        if(!Test.isRunningTest()) res = http.send(req);
        else res.setBody(SSOTestData.formResponse());

        system.debug('Request Body: ' + req.getBody());

        system.debug('\n\n----- SAML response body: ' + res.getBOdy());

        System.debug('\n\n----- Response Header Keys ' + json.serializePretty(res.getHeaderKeys()));
        for( String akey :res.getHeaderKeys()  )
        {
            system.debug('----- Key: ' + aKey + ' value ' + res.getHeader(aKey));
        }
        try
        {
            DOM.Document doc=new DOM.Document();
            doc.load(res.getBody());

            DOM.XmlNode rootNode=doc.getRootElement();
            string nodeValue = utilities.readXmlNode(rootNode,'SAMLResponse');

            accessToken = GetAccessTokenFromSAMLString(nodeValue);

            if(accessToken != null)
            {
                SaveTokenSetting(accessToken, dateTime.now(), TOKEN_VALID_MINS);
            }
        }
        catch(exception e)
        {
            log.addLog('GetIdpSaml', 'Unable to parse token response as XML. Assuming already logged in using existing session. ' +e.getMessage() + ' on line ' + e.getLineNumber() + '. Response body: ' +res.getBody());
        }
```

Comment: Could you use stored credentials to authenticate against the org as your connected app? One of the JS libraries might be handy on that front.

Comment: Not sure about using stored credentials, do you have any sample code? I'm not quite sure I follow how that would work.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to a SFDC org from another SFDC org?

Comment: @SebastianKessel I am trying to access a page within the same org but it is a standard page, and my code is of course custom, so the sessionId fetched on the custom code domain does not seem to be valid for the standard page domain.

Comment: This feels like an xy problem. Can you describe what problem led you to attempt to authenticate against the org you’re currently in?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by “standard page”?

Comment: So the problem we are trying to solve is that to get an API access token from the remote API, we first need to make a SAML request. The only way I know of to generate said request is through a connected app. There is no programatic way I know of to get all connected app information, so instead I have to make a request to the URL of the app and scrape the token that it would attempt to send when you click the continue button. If there is another way to generate a SAML token to include in the request programatically I'm all ears.

Comment: @Kenji776 What is the remote service you're trying to hit with a SAML token? Is it Salesforce or some other commercial app

Comment: The app is a private API managed by the client I'm working with. Not something others would likely have worked with. We did end up abandoning SAML in favor of the oAuth2 with JWT which the client only recently started supporting.